# Ruby block taking array or multiple parameters

Tags: ruby, block, enumerable

Today I was surprised to find ruby automatically find the values of an array given as a block parameter.

For example:

```
foo = "foo"
bar = "bar"
p foo.chars.zip(bar.chars).map { |pair| pair }.first #=> ["f", "b"]
p foo.chars.zip(bar.chars).map { |a, b| "#{a},#{b}" }.first #=> "f,b"
p foo.chars.zip(bar.chars).map { |a, b,c| "#{a},#{b},#{c}" }.first #=> "f,b,"
```

I would have expected the last two examples to give some sort of error.

1. Is this an example of a more general concept in ruby?
2. I don't think my wording at the start of my question is correct, what do I call what is happening here?

Comment: It's similar to (maybe the same as?) what happens with parallel assignment of variables from an array. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913765/why-does-ruby-parallel-assignment-with-array-of-strings-returns-string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ruby's block mechanics have a quirk to them, that is if you're iterating over something that contains arrays you can expand them out into different variables:

```
[ %w[ a b ], %w[ c d ] ].each do |a, b|
  puts 'a=%s b=%s' % [ a, b ]
end
```

This pattern is very useful when using `Hash#each` and you want to break out the `key` and `value` parts of the pair: `each { |k,v| ... }` is very common in Ruby code.

If your block takes more than one argument *and* the element being iterated is an array then it switches how the arguments are interpreted. You can always force-expand:

```
[ %w[ a b ], %w[ c d ] ].each do |(a, b)|
  puts 'a=%s b=%s' % [ a, b ]
end
```

That's useful for cases where things are more complex:

```
[ %w[ a b ], %w[ c d ] ].each_with_index do |(a, b), i|
  puts 'a=%s b=%s @ %d' % [ a, b, i ]
end
```

Since in this case it's iterating over an array *and* another element that's tacked on, so each item is actually a tuple of the form `%w[ a b ], 0` internally, which will be converted to an array if your block only accepts one argument.

This is much the same principle you can use when defining variables:

```
a, b = %w[ a b ]
a
# => 'a'
b
# => 'b'
```

That actually assigns independent values to `a` and `b`. Contrast with:

```
a, b = [ %w[ a b ] ]
a
# => [ 'a', 'b' ]
b
# => nil
```

Comment: So is the correct term for what's going on here is: "Ruby is expanding each array into the variables a, b, or c inside the block passed to the map instance method"?

Comment: @mbigras most languages refer to that as 'destructuring', ES6 now has it, LISP (http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node252.html), clojure (http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html) and many many more.

Comment: @akuhn The third example deals with multiple parameters which, if not broken out, are treated like an array.

Comment: There is a difference between `yield [a, b]` and `yield a, b` though in how they behave when the block expects one argument only.

Comment: The elements are not `[%w[a b], 0]` internally, see `[ %w[ a b ], %w[ c d ] ].each { |a| p a }` which prints just the elements without indices. Internally `each_with_index` yields a tuple to the block not an array. So it uses the equivalent of `yield each, index` and not `yield [each, index]`

Comment: @akuhn This array-to-tuple and tuple-to-array conversion is what we're talking about here, so yes, those are good examples of other situations where this comes up.

Comment: There is a subtlety here that your answer gets wrong. `each_with_index` does NOT create an array internally. This matters for blocks with `arity = 1`

Comment: @akuhn I see what you're saying and it's a good point. I've updated the phrasing to take that into account.

Comment: Almost there. "which will be converted to an array if your block only accepts one argument" is not correct, `%w[ a b ], 0` is not converted to an array for `arity = 1` blocks, this is exactly the difference between passing in an array versus a tuple. May take some time to study my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying there. I like your answer, but you should really move the output closer to the examples, it be considerably easier to follow. I'm also trying to describe the behaviour here in a more abstract way and the subtelty between tuple and array is hard to express. I've updated the phrasing again.

Comment: @akuhn I agree with tadman, would you mind moving the print statements  as `#=> foobar`s next to your yields? It would be easy to study :)

Answer (score 11):

Ruby block are quirky like that.

The rule is like this, if a block takes more than one argument and it is yielded a single object that responds to `to_ary` then that object is expanded. This makes yielding an array versus yielding a tuple seem to behave the same way for blocks that take two or more arguments.

`yield [a,b]` versus `yield a,b` do differ though when the block takes one argument only or when the block takes a variable number of arguments.

Let me demonstrate both of that

```
def yield_tuple
  yield 1, 2, 3
end

yield_tuple { |*a| p a }
yield_tuple { |a| p [a] }
yield_tuple { |a, b| p [a, b] }
yield_tuple { |a, b, c| p [a, b, c] }
yield_tuple { |a, b, c, d| p [a, b, c, d] }
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1] 
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, nil]
```

Whereas

```
def yield_array
  yield [1,2,3]
end

yield_array { |*a| p a }
yield_array { |a| p [a] }
yield_array { |a, b| p [a, b] }
yield_array { |a, b, c| p [a, b, c] }
yield_array { |a, b, c, d| p [a, b, c, d] }
```

prints

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3]] 
[1, 2] # array expansion makes it look like a tuple
[1, 2, 3] # array expansion makes it look like a tuple
[1, 2, 3, nil] # array expansion makes it look like a tuple
```

And finally to show that everything in Ruby uses duck-typing

```
class A
  def to_ary
    [1,2,3]
  end
end

def yield_arrayish
  yield A.new
end

yield_arrayish { |*a| p a }
yield_arrayish { |a| p [a] }
yield_arrayish { |a, b| p [a, b] }
yield_arrayish { |a, b, c| p [a, b, c] }
yield_arrayish { |a, b, c, d| p [a, b, c, d] }
```

prints

```
[#<A:0x007fc3c2969190>]
[#<A:0x007fc3c2969050>]
[1, 2] # array expansion makes it look like a tuple
[1, 2, 3] # array expansion makes it look like a tuple
[1, 2, 3, nil] # array expansion makes it look like a tuple
```

PS, the same array expansion behavior applies for `proc` closures which behave like blocks, whereas `lambda` closures behave like methods.

Answer (score 4):

> I would have expected the last two examples to give some sort of error.

It does in fact work that way if you pass a `proc` from a method. Yielding to such a proc is much stricter – it checks its arity and doesn't attempt to convert an array argument to an argument list:

```
def m(a, b)
  "#{a}-#{b}"
end

['a', 'b', 'c'].zip([0, 1, 2]).map(&method(:m))
#=> wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) (ArgumentError)
```

This is because `zip` creates an array (of arrays) and `map` just yields each element, i.e.

```
yield ['a', 0]
yield ['b', 1]
yield ['c', 2]
```

`each_with_index` on the other hand works:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].each_with_index.map(&method(:m))
#=> ["a-0", "b-1", "c-2"]
```

because it yields two separate values, the element and its index, i.e.

```
yield 'a', 0
yield 'b', 1
yield 'c', 2
```

Comment: Good point. You could also use a `lambda` to demonstrate that. `[1,2,3].each &lambda { |a,b| }` fails but `[1,2,3].each &proc { |a,b| }` works.