# Why does Ruby support trailing commas in method invocations but not in method definitions?

Tags: ruby

For example, this is valid Ruby:

```rb
def foo(bar, baz); end
foo(1, 2,)
```

but this is not

```rb
def foo(bar, baz,); end # syntax error, unexpected ')' (SyntaxError)
foo(1,2,)
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75596144/trailing-comma-in-ruby-parameter-signature (I did not tag it as such since it is not exact and my close flag would close the question)

Comment: Short answer: "Because Matz".  Long answer: It's not supported by the parser, and nobody wanted it to be supported. Trailing commas in lists are a tradition, though, like Python's odd tuple syntax `(x,)` vs. `(x)` which is not a tuple.

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes I think this is distinct: that question is about block parameter signatures, not method signatures (though I guess those are related)

Comment: "Block parameter signatures" aren't a thing in Ruby. You probably meant to call them method arguments or Array/Hash literals. In your example, the list of numbers in parentheses when calling `foo(1,2,)` is actually parsed as an Array of positional arguments. You can see this in action with `def foo(*args) = pp args; foo(1,2,) #=> [1, 2]`. As explained in my answer, an Array can have trailing commas which is why it works for passing parameters. However, it will *not* work if you omit the parenthetical arguments; the parser won't understand `foo 1,2,` but is perfectly happy with `foo 1, 2`.

Comment: That's not what I'm referring to, though "block parameter signatures" may not be the right term for it. I'm talking about the tokens `|a,b|` in an expression like`foo { |a, b| a * b }`, which the official docs call "block arguments". If we're being hyper-technical, a block isn't a method (nor an actual object), though it can be converted to one quite easily with the `&` (block conversion) operator.

Comment: @pixatlazaki The example block in your comment immediately above is different than the method call in your OP. A block takes block arguments which are assigned to block variables. A method takes an optional block, but doesn't take "block arguments." When you call a method with arguments, you are passing positional or keyword arguments, and possibly a block. You are not defining block arguments, though, although you could certainly pass the other arguments *to* a block from within your method. That's why terminology matters.

Comment: After thinking about it, while it's the wrong way to describe the example in your OP, you *could* call `|a, b|` from your comment about `foo { |a, b| a * b }` a "block parameter signature" of sorts, but I think most people would just call them "block variables" to distinguish them from method signatures. All of which is largely beside the point, and presents a motte-and-bailey fallacy. The issue in your OP is about implicit Array objects as arguments to methods, and @engineerminsky's linked post explains the semantics of using a trailing comma when defining a list of block variables. Pick one.

Answer (score 0):

### It's Useful Syntactic Sugar for Objects, But Not Method Signatures

In the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78070048/why-does-ruby-support-trailing-commas-in-method-invocations-but-not-in-method-de#comment137632583_78070048), you received what seems like a valid answer. However, it might help to understand *why* trailing commas are often considered useful in Array or Hash definitions, but not in method signatures.

1. Method signatures should be short. Very long lists in a method signature are an anti-pattern, so adding support for that in the parser wouldn't make a lot of sense.
2. An Array or Hash can be arbitrarily long, and supporting trailing commas allows you to re-order elements without having to add or delete two commas when sorting or moving lines; that programmer friction and (presumably) the ease of applying some language lubricant justified the parser support for that use case.
3. The underlying implementation of how trailing commas are handled in Array or Hash literals and block variable definitions might not work for parsing method signatures, which have a large set of edge cases anyway.

#### Why Ignoring Trailing Commas in Arrays & Hashes is Useful

Consider the following minimalist example:

```rb
foo = [
  "4B1EDDEB-3B54-494A-9B79-FE864E8A4B84",
  "5AB88925-2C0F-4E26-AB12-554A0DD0BD6E",
  "F9265B1C-353E-4355-8B86-08428998EE16",
  "6E5D5D6C-A0C1-47A4-97F8-C4FF080BE1E0",
  "39D97755-7691-43F1-9446-07A10E138D93"
]
```

If you want move the fifth element of the *foo* Array in your source code manually (as opposed to programmatically with #pop and #unshift) so that it becomes the first element, you could easily forget to add the trailing comma to the line you just moved, or forget to remove the trailing comma at the end of the Array.

Now imagine you have 100 such elements and try to sort the lines. It's *very* easy to lose track of the two lines that would need to be adjusted when one line without a comma is buried somewhere inside a wall of text like that. That's even *more* true when the lines or elements are not of uniform length such as the UUIDs above. A ragged right margin can make spotting the missing comma much, much harder.

By allowing each line to end with a comma, whether or not it's at the end of an Array or Hash literal, the trailing-comma syntax allows you to avoid that problem. With trailing commas, you can cut-and-paste without worrying about accidentally creating a syntax error that might be hard to spot visually.

#### Considerations for Method Signatures

First of all, method signatures have a lot more factors for the parser to consider. The same approach use to discard a trailing comma in a collection such as an Array, Hash, or even a list of block variables might not work for method definitions.

Secondly, a method definition that has only one comma-delimited element per line is pretty rare, so the reordering friction that a large Array or Hash creates is arguably less significant. Maybe you could write your method definitions that way, but it's not a common use case and doesn't drive the same level of benefit.

Thirdly, a method that defines a hundred *explicit* variables in its signature is not something you should ever see. In such cases the code should receive an Array or Hash, aggregate splatted positional or keyword arguments such as `def foo(*args, **kwargs); end`, or even take an options Hash. Heck, if you use instance variables or attribute readers, you might not need to pass anything at all! So, while you might occasionally see a method or two in the wild where you have more than a single line for your method signature, especially when inheriting from Struct, you won't find much well-written code that would really benefit from trailing-comma support when parsing a method definition.

#### "Ask Matz"

Pragmatically, distinguishing the different use cases makes sense to me even though I agree that there's a slight disjoint between the implementations of object literals and method definitions. You could even add the [Array destructuring done by trailing commas when defining block variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75596563/1301972) to the list of Ruby language oddities if you like. Ultimately, someone thought it important enough to solve for trailing commas in literals and block variables despite the differing semantics of those two things, and regardless of whether the handling of those use cases share a common implementation under the hood. Either the same solution wouldn't work for method definitions, or no one thought it worth doing for some reason. I would bet on the former, based on the long road to Ruby's current implementations of keyword arguments and the complexities of implementing the `*` and `...` forwarding arguments.

If the inconsistency bothers you, then you should search the [bug tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/) to see if this was a deliberate decision by the Ruby Core Team for technical reasons, or if it's just because no one has bothered to submit a patch for it before. I suspect the former, since it *does* provide some useful syntactic sugar for the objects that really need it without causing parsing problems for sane method definitions. I myself don't find the behavior surprising or particularly inconsistent, so I've never considered it a bug and therefore can't point you to a specific issue or discussion thread where the matter was decided, but that's where you'll find the canonical answer if there is one.

Comment: In my current codebase, I see 23 instances of splitting a method signature across multiple lines, so I don't necessarily buy the reasoning that method signatures should be short enough for this to be a non-issue. But I do think everyone is right here that it's either by mistake or by personal preference.

Comment: The question is about the inconsistency between method _definition_ (doesn't allow trailing comma) and method _invocation_ (does allow trailing comma).

Comment: @Stefan See my [comment on the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78070048/why-does-ruby-support-trailing-commas-in-method-invocations-but-not-in-method-de/78073554?noredirect=1#comment137660687_78070048). The parser usually treats comma-delimited arguments to a method as an implicit Array, and Array objects allow for trailing commas; it's really that simple. `foo(*[1, 2,]) == foo(1, 2) #=> true`. Q.E.D.

Comment: Good point, the underlying parser might indeed be the same for both, array literals and argument lists. But isn't it odd that the parser differs when it comes to method _definitions_?

Comment: @Stefan I agree it seems odd, but don't find it unreasonable. Block variables use trailing commas for null destructuring. Maybe arrays do the same thing with the "missing" element from a trailing comma, but since method signatures have so many other complexities that might be impractical there. These are each weird edge cases, albeit with some utility value, so I have no idea of the level of effort to normalize them all. I offered what I consider a valid explanation of the status quo, but am certainly not defending the disjoint. I'll go with "Ask Matz," assuming it isn't just legacy cruft.